# Give me a example of non-RESTful design?

Tags: rest

I learned the term "RESTful" as a Rails developer. After reading wikipedia, also [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) and [here](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife).

I don't get it. It seems to me, Rails is only using a **concise** way to describe URLs. It seems to me every URI is RESTful, in it's designed **scope**.

For example, I think `GET /delete?student_id=3` is RESTful **in the scope the the application itself**.

Can anybody tell me which constrict does it violate? Please refer the constrict from the [REST definition](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

Answer (score 16):

A `GET` request should be *idempotent* and the request should not leave any side-effects on the server. Quoting from the [HTTP spec sec 9.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the `GET` and `HEAD` methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe". This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

Therefore `GET /delete?student_id=3` already violates the idempotency assumption of the `GET` verb, since it will delete a record on the server.

A RESTful interface is a uniform interface, which in other words means that a `GET` is supposed to behave as required by the HTTP spec. And this is what [the spec says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3):

> The `GET` method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an
>      entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers
>      to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be
>      returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the
>      process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.
>
> ...

Comment: It's violate the HTTP spec. Not the REST spec.

Comment: @Cheng: Yes, it shouldn't violate the HTTP spec. It's not a uniform interface anymore if it doesn't conform to some spec.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo +1 although this should probably be rephrased as "A GET request should be idempotent /and/ the request should not leave any side-effects [...]". PUT is idempotent too, but it has side-effects.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks, you're right. I'll update my answer. +1ed your answer earlier :)

Comment: What if it conforms to a spec that defined by myself? I can see it conforms the HTTP spec only for convenience. It's not necessary to make an application RESTful.

Comment: @Cheng: You can in theory. Quoting from the Wikipedia Article: "REST was initially described in the context of HTTP, but is not limited to that protocol. RESTful architectures can be based on other Application Layer protocols if they already provide a rich and uniform vocabulary for applications based on the transfer of meaningful representational state. RESTful applications maximize the use of the pre-existing, well-defined interface and other built-in capabilities provided by the chosen network protocol, and minimize the addition of new application-specific features on top of it."

Comment: "Therefore GET /delete?student_id=3 already violates the idempotency assumption of the GET verb, since it will delete a record on the server." This isn't violating idempotency (DELETE itself is idempotent) but rather that it should be safe.

Answer (score 8):

> It seems to me, Rails is only using a
>   concise way to describe URLs. It seems
>   to me every URI is RESTful, in it's
>   designed scope.

URIs are neither RESTful or non-RESTful. REST is an architectural style for which you need to consider the overall application.

`GET` is the method for the retrieval request. If you want to put this in the context of the REST dissertation, if your `GET` request has side-effects, it will then break a few other constraints, for example regarding the cache.

You could also potentially design a RESTful system where a `GET /delete?student_id=3` request gives you a representation telling you (or asking you to confirm) that you want to delete that student, so long as it doesn't actually perform the delete operation.

Answer (score 2):

A GET should be safe to be RESTful, but obviously combined with a delete it is unsafe.

So it looks RESTful but doesn't act RESTful.  So it fails the [duck test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test).

Answer (score 1):

See Section 5.1.5.  Your example violates the uniform interface constraint.  It does this by violating the HTTP spec.