# RESTful reset password and confirm email

Tags: rest, uri

im thinking what is the best RESTful way how confirm email and request reseting password. Im only aiming to find correct URI...

confirm email

`PUT /users/{userId}/confirmEmail?code=xyz` - does not seem much RESTful because of confirmEmail

`PUT /users/{userId}/email?confirmedBy=xyz` - maybe better? dunno

reset password (similar problem)

`PUT /users/{userId}/resetPassword --DATA {email:xyz@xyz.xy}` - same thinkin as before

`PUT /users/{userId}/password --DATA {state:reseted,resent:xyz@xyz.xy}` - hmmm... again Im not sure

are there any better ways in your mind?:-)

Comment: Why use `PUT` and not `POST`? You're not really setting a new representation for the resource you're addressing (and it's not necessarily idempotent either).

Comment: yes ok, could be POST I agree. But Im aiming for URI..

Comment: If you want to do it the REST way, the URI structure should be secondary to the hypermedia (the way you tell the client what to do with this URI). URIs are meant to be opaque and their structure is about how you implement the action internally. You may be interested in these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889099/give-me-a-example-of-non-restful-design/3889341#3889341 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044391/rest-get-verb-with-parameters/4044656#4044656

Answer (score 10):

If you want your URIs to refer to resources, then call the resource `confirmation` and POST confirmations to user accounts.

```
POST /users/{userid}/confirmation
```

Answer (score 5):

The true RESTful answer is the URL does not matter, you put it in the confirmation e-mail anyway for the recipient to follow. Use whatever is most convenient for your load balancer, reverse proxy, servers, etc.

For convenience you'll end up accepting the confirmation even if it comes in a GET request, because that's what the browsers of flesh-and-bones humans oblivious to Dr Roy T. Fielding et al. send when clicking on a link in an e-mail :-)

Having established it is completely academic, I'd argue you were right to think of PUT, as the client idempotently places evidence of having access to the e-mail. Repeating the request has no further effect.

Comment: From a technical standpoint, URL structure really doesn't matter to having a request process successfully. From an ease-of-understanding, API discovery and maintainability perspective, they make a massive difference. Trying to argue URL structure doesn't matter is like arguing that the names of classes doesn't matter.

Comment: Yupp, I think we are saying the same thing, just as Class names do not matter to the JVM, you are free to chose them at the comfort of the programmers. API discovery in this case is receiving the e-mail, a human recognizing there's a confirmation link in there, and clicking it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that he said a reset service for someone who forgot her password, and not a change password service for someone already logged in...

I would use 2 services. 1st to request the reset password mail, and 2nd to set the new password with the token received in the received mail.

**For the 1st:**
POST baseUrl/passwordReset
Request body

```
{
   "email" : "my@self.com"
}
```

This could be POST or PUT, but since a mail delivery is not a resource subject to CRUD anyway, let's not be pedantic and use the old POST that was always used in html forms.

Obviously I would control that the same client (ip? browser? ...) doesn't make me send 20K mails in a minute.

Sending the mail to the user doesn't imply that the old password is not valid. That will only happen later in the second request when the new one updates it.

Response 204 (perhaps you should do it even if you don't know that email, because if you return error that means that when you don't return error you are confirming to a stranger that the given email is registered)

**For the 2nd:**
POST baseUrl/password
Request body

```
{
    "token" : "3D21BA...4F",
    "newPassword" : "m%4pW1!O"
}
```

Where the token is received in the mail. So the mail could have a link to a page including the token, when the page is loaded, the form is filled and submitted, being the token a hidden field that some javascript reads from the URL and puts here.

This is really a resource that you update, so POST. And I don't think it makes sense to have the same URI with 2 verbs for both, because they are not the same resource/entity at all.

*Add*
By the way, I would make both HTTPS only, and that's why I put all the sensitive information in the body, not URL parameters.

Comment: This is where my logic lead me as well. I am using the exact same principle.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think that `PUT` is the right method for this. `PUT` broadly means "put this here", where the URL is identifying where the content should be located. You're really asking an existing resource to perform some action, which makes `POST` more correct.

To answer your direct question, a RESTful URL should identify the resource you want to handle your request. In this case, the resource is either the user, or some password-resetting resource within the user.

My preference would be for a password-resetting resource:

`POST /users/{userid}/password-reset`

This makes sense from a HTTP point of view, since you could issue a `GET` on the resource and receive something which indicates how to action a password reset (e.g. a HTML form prompting for the email address of the associated account).

**EDIT:**

For the purposes of email validation, there are two obvious options. You could either `POST` to a "confirm email" resource with the email address and confirmation data, to ask the server to process the confirmation, or you can execute a `PUT` to put the confirmation information on the server:

`POST /users/{userid}/confirm-email`

or

`PUT /users/{userid}/email-confirmation`

Comment: I commented POST in previous post, I agree. Nvm, let's identify as password-reset resource. Then i guess you would add similary email-confirm resource? And adding query parameter or data for code?

Comment: When you say "confirm email" what do you mean exactly? What part of the process requires the user to confirm their email? The question could do to be edited to include your use case.

Comment: thats kinda classic stuff after registration. You register, then you recieve email with confirmation code which u send to server and ur email is now treated as confirmed.

Comment: The limitation here will be your email client: it probably will only do HTTP GET operations, which is not RESTful for this action; GET should only retrieve a representation of a resource and should not have side-effects (like updating a user's account). I think you'll have to break away the RESTful model to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yep I was thinking of that. And I wont have to do it bad. The RESTful interface is used for contacting application logic. This interface is called by web front-end. So I will create some GET URL to front-end, there will be some form with filled code (from email) and by submitting this form, the web app will call REST API and it doesnt matter what method it calls (it can call anything)

Comment: Updated my answer with something more relevant to your proposed flow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a RESTful way.

**Request**

```
PUT /{userid}/email HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/json+confirmation-code

{"activateCode": "23sfgsg3twt3rgsdhgs"}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/json+email-status
{"email": "my-email@address.com", "active": "true"}
```

No verbs in the URI needed :)

Comment: Now, if only you could make that clickable in email.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything wrong with having confirmEmail like the 1st example. In the URL you have the key to the user, confirmEmail is the action, and the data with that action is in the query string.

Comment: well, as far as I know. Doing RESTful interface is always a compromise, but you should be looking on URI as on the way in the graph. Adding an action into the URI is imho not RESTful. This URI tells me, between users, find specified user and his confirmEmail, strange...

Comment: @dxxx, there's nothing wrong with putting an action name in the URI, so long as getting the representation at that URI doesn't actually perform that action (but provides you with a form telling the client how to do this action, for example). (Similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889099/give-me-a-example-of-non-restful-design/3889341#3889341).)

Comment: well I was learned not to do that, thats why im trying to find another way. I know that resource != model. That resource is just something different than object with attributes. But still having an action within URI seems... I dont know..., just bad feelind:-)

Comment: Call it confirmationEmail if the verb orientation of the word confirm doesn't sit well with you.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently worked on this, my take was

`POST /{base_url}/password`

because I was actually creating a new random password and sending it over to the user

and

`PUT /{base_url}/confirmation?token=...`

Because I am updating the confirmation that was already sent out when the user registered.